# Thymeleaf - The difference between th:field="${}" and th:field="*{}"

Tags: thymeleaf

I can't find on the tutorial the difference between this two instructions.

**th:field="${something}"** and **th:field="*{something}"**

Can anyone show me some example?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

[Reference site](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standarddialect5minutes.html)

Five types:

- `${...}` : Variable expressions. These are OGNL expressions (or Spring
  EL if you have spring integrated)
- `*{...}` : Selection expressions. Same as above, excepted it will be executed on a previously selected object only
- `#{...}` : Message (i18n) expressions. Used to retrieve locale-specific messages from external sources
- `@{...}` : Link (URL) expressions. Used
  to build URLs
- `~{...}` : Fragment expressions. Represent fragments of
  markup and move them around templates