# What is the difference between th:field="${something}" and th:field="*{something}"?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am new to thymeleaf and I don't understand the difference between `th:field="${something}"` and `th:field="*{something}"`. When to use * and when to use $?

Comment: Did you check this ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37728515/thymeleaf-the-difference-between-thfield-and-thfield/40028263

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Thymeleaf - The difference between th:field="${}" and th:field="\*{}"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37728515/thymeleaf-the-difference-between-thfield-and-thfield)

Comment: @Varun if you found my answer helpful and solving your question you can mark it as an Accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the thymeleaf documentation

> Variable expressions not only can be written in ${...} expressions,
>   but also in *{...} ones.
>
> There is an important difference, though: the asterisk syntax
>   evaluates expressions on selected objects rather than on the whole
>   context variables map. This is: as long as there is no selected
>   object, the dollar and the asterisk syntaxes do exactly the same.

From [here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html) in the *4.3 Expressions on selections (asterisk syntax)* section.

Technically the difference is that if you have selected an Object 
like so `th:object="${session.user}`
then you can use the * for the properties of the user object 
like so `th:text="*{lastName}"`

If you haven't selected an object they are the same.